# Track hits over many domains

Tags: php, jquery, counter, hit

a quick question.

I'm looking at doing a multi-domain hit counter over many different domains, preferabbly in PHP.
What would the best way to track each hit be?

I was thinking storing a central database and updating the number in the database every time a page on any domain is loaded - but wouldn't that have major performance issues?
I was also thinking about 'basic number stored in text option' - but is it possible to edit a file from different servers/domains.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Like Google Analytics or Piwik?

Comment: I've used Analytics before - not sure how easy/quick it would be to get the total amount of hits over a large amount of hits.

Answer (score 1):

if i get you right then you have different websites that sit on different servers?
in this case i'm not sure about editing a file from a different server and i wouldn't go there.
instead of editing a remote file, just update a remote DB ([example](http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/))

best solution is using a non-blocking servers (like nodejs) which will update a DB on every page load (you can easily access remote DBs on other servers, or send a curl call to designated file on a master server). by using non-blocking web servers you will not slow down the page's load time.

google's analytics works a bit differently - it loads a script from google-analytics.com and this script gets all the info. the problem is that this only happens after the DOM has loaded.
if you are going for a solution like this - just put an AJAX call at the top of every page that you want to monitor.

Comment: Thanks! Would you recommend a non-blocking DB over mySQL (Which is what I usually use)

Comment: the buzz today is about non-blocking web servers and noSQL databases. don't confuse the between them.
i find noSQL databases (like [Mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/)) far easier and faster to work with than SQL DBs (like mySQL). [look at this benchmark](http://www.moredevs.ro/mysql-vs-mongodb-performance-benchmark/)
every DB has got its flaws. but in your case I recommend you give Mongodb a try - use multiple domains and get each domain to connect to the same remote DB.